# mod_rewrite sends request to the right place, but the CSS file is not loading?

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I'm having a go at mod_rewrite so that the client can list better urls on Google

So I've created a page (www.cruiseandmaritime.com/cruise_details_by_name.php which is where I send things like

www.cruiseandmaritime.com/cruises/French-Leave

works fine, the page loads with the right data, but there is no stylesheet loaded so it's all just unformatted

Now I'm guessing, that because I have created the imaginary directory 'cruises' its something to with that... ?

Here is my line in the .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteBase     /
RewriteRule     ^cruises/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$      cruise_details_by_name.php?id=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle requests for all cruises
```

once again, any help greatly appreciated !

Rich:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's a mod_rewrite problem.

In your html code there's a link to your css file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/anytime.css" />
```

Currently the browser is trying to load the file located at `http://www.cruiseandmaritime.com/cruises/stylesheets/anytime.css`

If you let the file path start with `/` this should work. That way an absolute uri is used instead of a relative one.

Comment: yep, that's it ! Ni Swan. I'll tick it when it lets me.